# How to share files with coworkers via internet? Securely?

Tags: sharing

I have number of co-workers in other countries. I would like to be able to setup something like shared network drive so that we can all access the files and work together. What's the best way of doing that? Do I need Lion server for that?

Comment: re Securely - how secure do you need it to be?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use something like [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)?

There's also [Sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/) which allows you to host files yourself.

Comment: Or [Box.net](http://www.box.net/)

Comment: yeah... but I was more looking at something "in house" i.e. myself hosting the files.

Comment: sparkleshare looks good. But when I tried to run in on my Mac (lion) it didn't work...

Comment: Why not create a new question with whatever problem you're having. Somebody might be able to help you

Comment: If everyone is running Lion, perhaps you can do something like AirDrop?

Comment: Airdrop won't allow them to share files over the internet

Answer (score 3):

[OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/index.php/Main_Page) lets you setup your own cloud server environment.

Comment: I just set it up on my computer, it works great!